# Importing CGM format using QGIS

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, export, import, file-formats

I would like to know is it possible to read or import a CGM file using QGISand also export other file format back to CGM using QGIS.(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_Graphics_Metafile)
Is there any existing plugin for this or if we need to implement a new plugin is is it possible using QGIS